# Hibernate Exception while defining mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I am working on a project and using Hibernate for database interaction.

I have two tables, one is `RESOURCE_PROFILE` and second is `PROJECT_MASTER`. Below are the DDL statements.

```
CREATE TABLE USER_PROFILE (
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    MIDDLE_NAME VARCHAR(15),
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    EMAIL_ID VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    USER_ID VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    PASSWORD VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    ROLE VARCHAR(20),
    SUPERVISOR_ID VARCHAR(20),
    SUBMITTED_BY VARCHAR(20),
    SUBMITTED_DATE DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE PROJECT_MASTER (
    PROJECT_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PROJECT_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PROJECT_NUMBER VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    START_DATE DATE,
    END_DATE DATE,
    PROJECT_MANAGER_ID VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    PROJECT_SUPERVISOR_ID VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    SUBMITTED_BY VARCHAR(40),
    SUBMITTED_DATE DATE,
    UPDATED_BY VARCHAR(40),
    PRIMARY KEY (PROJECT_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (PROJECT_MANAGER_ID) REFERENCES USER_PROFILE(USER_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (PROJECT_SUPERVISOR_ID) REFERENCES USER_PROFILE(USER_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (SUBMITTED_BY) REFERENCES USER_PROFILE(USER_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (UPDATED_BY) REFERENCES USER_PROFILE(USER_ID)
);
```

As you can see in the `PROJECT_MASTER` table I am using the `USER_ID(RESOURCE_PROFILE)` as a foreign key for multiple columns in `PROJECT_MASTER` table. Below is the entity class I created for these two tables. I am sure that I am doing something wrong in the mapping, can you please help me and point me to the right direction?
Since I have the same foreign key getting used for multiple columns, how can I achieve this mapping?

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "PROJECT_MASTER")
    public class ProjectMasterBean  {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue
      @Column(name="PROJECT_ID")
      private int projectID;

      @Column(name="PROJECT_NAME")
      private String projectName;

      @Column(name="PROJECT_NUMBER")
      private String projectNumber;

      @Column(name="START_DATE")
      private Date startDate;

      @Column(name="END_DATE")
      private Date endDate;

      @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID",insertable=false, updatable=false,
            nullable=false)
      private UserProfileBean projectManagerID;

      @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID",insertable=false, updatable=false,
            nullable=false)
      private UserProfileBean projectSupervisorID;

      @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID",insertable=false, updatable=false,
            nullable=false)
      private UserProfileBean submittedBy;
    }

      @Column(name="SUBMITTED_DATE")
      private Date submittedDate;

      @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID",insertable=false, updatable=false,
            nullable=false)
      private UserProfileBean updatedBy;


     public class UserProfileBean  {
    @Id
      @Column(name="USER_ID")
      private String userID;

      @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
      private String firstName;

      @Column(name="MIDDLE_NAME")
      private String middleName;

      @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
      private String lastName;

      @Column(name="EMAIL_ID")
      private String emailID;

      @Column(name="PASSWORD")
      private String password;

      @Column(name="ROLE")
      private String userRole;

      @Column(name="SUPERVISOR_ID")
      private String supervisorID;

      @Column(name="SUBMITTED_BY")
      private String submittedBy;

      @Column(name="SUBMITTED_DATE")
      private String submittedDate;
}
```

This is the exception I am getting:

> Hibernate: insert into PROJECT_MASTER (PROJECT_NAME, PROJECT_NUMBER, START_DATE, END_DATE, SUBMITTED_BY, SUBMITTED_DATE, UPDATED_BY) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
>   Sep 12, 2013 8:46:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
>   SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet action threw exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: Field 'PROJECT_MANAGER_ID' doesn't have a default value
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
```

Insert Query doesn't even have those two columns. This is how the query should be.

> Hibernate: insert into PROJECT_MASTER (PROJECT_NAME, PROJECT_NUMBER, START_DATE, END_DATE, PROJECT_MANAGET_ID , PROJECT_SUPERVISOR_ID , SUBMITTED_BY, SUBMITTED_DATE, UPDATED_BY) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?,?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created your table with

> CREATE TABLE PROJECT_MASTER ( PROJECT_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   PROJECT_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, PROJECT_NUMBER VARCHAR(50) NOT
>   NULL, START_DATE DATE, END_DATE DATE, **PROJECT_MANAGER_ID VARCHAR(40)
>   NOT NULL**, PROJECT_SUPERVISOR_ID VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, SUBMITTED_BY
>   VARCHAR(40), SUBMITTED_DATE DATE, UPDATED_BY VARCHAR(40), PRIMARY KEY
>   (PROJECT_ID), **FOREIGN KEY (PROJECT_MANAGER_ID) REFERENCES
>   USER_PROFILE(USER_ID)**, FOREIGN KEY (PROJECT_SUPERVISOR_ID) REFERENCES
>   USER_PROFILE(USER_ID), FOREIGN KEY (SUBMITTED_BY) REFERENCES
>   USER_PROFILE(USER_ID), FOREIGN KEY (UPDATED_BY) REFERENCES
>   USER_PROFILE(USER_ID) );

And you've made your class uses this Table. Because you don't have a default value for a `NOT NULL` field, Hibernate complains. Either delete that column from the table or add a relationship in your entity mapping.

Change to

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="PROJECT_MANAGER_ID ",insertable=false, updatable=false,
        nullable=false)
private UserProfileBean projectManagerID;
```

Comment: I want to have these columns in the table, and I need to store the userid (from resource table) of the project manager and project supervisor in that table.

Comment: Thats what the question is, How or what to add the relationship in the entity class.

Comment: @user2773890 Missed that. Added an edit. The `name` attribute on the `@JoinColumn` is the name of column acting as the foreign key on the current table. Make to `PROJECT_MANAGER_ID`.

Comment: And even i add 'Project_Manager_ID', How does hibernate gets to know that it needs to add USER_ID of a different table ?

Comment: @user2773890 You have to do the same thing for all the columns that are referencing other entities. Hibernate has defaults. It'll check the type of the field, ex. `UserProfileBean`. It will then look at that class to see if it is an `@Entity` and map to its `@Id` field, which it can then know is mapped to `USER_ID` because of the `@Column` annotation.